# Android Proguard - how to keep onClick handlers only referenced from XML layouts

Tags: android, proguard

In my Android app I ofter don't create a View's on-click handler in code, but rely on the ability to specify it in the XML layout file, like this:

```
   <Button
        ....
        android:onClick="onSearchClicked"
       ...../>
```

And then have the method in the Activity like this:

```
    public void onSearchClicked( View v ) {
    ........}
```

Meaning there is no obvious reference to this method in my own code.

When running Proguard for a production release it seems to remove this method and the on-click fails.

What can I add to my proguard config file to avoid this that won't oblige me to rename all these methods?

- An annotation I could add to the method and have proguard take notice of?
- Somehow specify these types of methods referenced from xml?
- I suppose I can add a false reference in the code, but would like to avoid that if I can as I won't always remember to put it in!

I have looked through the proguard examples for Android and can't see anything for this particular need.

Comment: Again. No direct answer that fits the bill, and I can't vote for my own answer that does.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This seems to be the best answer, as it is 100% robust to naming of such methods:

```
# This will avoid all the onClick listeners referenced from XML Layouts from being removed
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
       public void *(android.view.View); 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i added the above code but I am still getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity`

Comment: Is it public and matches the method signature required for onClick handlers?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes it was public but I found the problem to be related to other function called in the onClick. Therefore no worries.

Answer (score 1):

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
   public void onSearchClicked(android.view.View );
}
```

but double check it from proguard doc :
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/refcard.html

Comment: I thought of that, but in an Activity I may have a lof of these, all with different names. And any change to my code will require a change to my proguard config....I'm looking for a more robust way.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
       public void on*Click(android.view.View); 
}
```

and then I name all onClick methods like: onCancelBtnClick(), onBackgroundClick(), etc.