# App Crashes when I click any button

Tags: android, android-button

My app crashes whenever I click on any button. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

The error is I get is

> Error - Could not find method openMastermind(View) in a parent or
>   ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button1'

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


ArrayList<Guess> guesses = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listview;
//ImageButton checkButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.checkButton);
private ImageView[] guessViews;
private Colour[] currentGuess = new Colour[4];
private int guessPosition = 0;
private Colour[] solution = new Colour[4];

public void openInstructions(View view) {
    Intent startInstructionsActivity = new Intent(this, Instructions.class);
    startActivity(startInstructionsActivity);
}

public void openMastermind(View view) {
    Intent startMastermindActivity = new Intent(this, mastermind1.class);
    startActivity(startMastermindActivity);
}

public void openHighscores(View view) {
    Intent startHighscoresActivity = new Intent(this, Highscores.class);
    startActivity(startHighscoresActivity);
}

public MainActivity() {

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
        solution[i] = Colour.values()[r.nextInt(Colour.values().length)];
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mastermind1);


    final ListAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, guesses);
    listview = getListView();

    listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    guessViews = new ImageView[4];
    guessViews[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guess1);
    guessViews[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guess2);
    guessViews[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guess3);
    guessViews[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guess4);
```

And here is the xml file that contains the buttons.

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#006699">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Mastermind"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/play_button"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:onClick="openMastermind"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView" />

<Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/instructions_button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="openInstructions"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/highscores_button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:onClick="openHighscores"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the logcat of the crash

```
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.i7678939.mastermind4, PID: 2506
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method openMastermind(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button1'
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-21 19:18:30.788 2506-2506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-21 19:18:30.799 262-475/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.i7678939.mastermind4/.mastermind1
02-21 19:18:30.857 62-62/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 62: eglCreateSyncKHR(1243): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
02-21 19:18:31.302 262-764/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-21 19:18:31.390 262-764/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-21 19:18:31.391 262-764/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3bd6b20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-21 19:18:31.498 262-280/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{eb0a95a u0 com.example.i7678939.mastermind4/.mastermind1 t22 f}
02-21 19:18:31.857 262-272/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18556(1531KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(220KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 7MB/10MB, paused 6.822ms total 943.879ms
02-21 19:18:31.987 262-715/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityStack$ActivityStackHandler.handleMessage(android.os.Message) from ActivityStack.java:283 waiters=0 for 110ms
02-21 19:18:32.317 690-770/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-21 19:18:32.317 690-770/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3cddec0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-21 19:18:33.593 1002-1013/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 28190(1126KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 2.418ms total 389.758ms
02-21 19:18:42.119 262-280/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{eb0a95a u0 com.example.i7678939.mastermind4/.mastermind1 t22 f}
```

Comment: How about to add StackTrace of the crash?

Comment: Oh sorry ill add the logcat now

Comment: Whats the name of the layout you have attached which contains buttons? is it `activity_mastermind1` and use this code to set adapter `setListAdapter(myAdapter);` you dont need listview instance as the activity is already ListActivity

Comment: The layout attached is activity_main.xml

Comment: I don't understand. activity_main.xml signifies that the layout should be for Main Activity (as per android naming conventions) however you are using some other layout in your code `setContentView(R.layout.activity_mastermind1);`

Comment: What is activity_main.xml? is it your layout for listview items?

Comment: What is the name of the XML file which you posted here? What are the contents of `activity_mastermind1.xml`?

Comment: does `mastermind1.class` exist? Do the other buttons work?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set Button's onClickListener in Activity class code, not in XML layout. That practice makes Your code better and more relieble. Better keep UI xml and application logic separeted.

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             openInstructions(v);
         }
     });
```

Comment: "Better keep UI xml and application logic separeted." - References please. They are separated. Declaring the method in XML is accepted and encouraged practice.

Comment: Declaring onClick Listener in code is more flexible solution, as for me. It's easier to understand app logic, when all view events handled right in Activity/fragment code, not in XML. So that is just IMHO and avice.

Comment: You could basically say "don't use xml at all and draw every component in java"- there is no mixing of UI and application logic in either case.

Comment: Also, ProGuard mechanisms will delete methods that called from XML by default.

Comment: ProGuard mechanisms - reference please? Since when? Seeing as the compiler converts xml to java in the first place...

Comment: Android use reflection mechanism for calling methods declared in onClick. 
Also You can google for "android xml onclick proguard" and see how many people faced with that problem.

Just for example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216685/android-proguard-how-to-keep-onclick-handlers-only-referenced-from-xml-layouts

Of course there is solution, but why do we need to complicate the simple things?

Comment: If you feel writing 5 lines of code for each button justifies writing 2 if/when you use proguard, and frankly the issue looks 4 years dated and I've never experienced it with Android Studio, then no one is stopping you. But it is plainly incorrect to tell new Android devs that xml is worse or less reliable, that it mixes ui/application logic (android isn't mvc anyway), or that it isn't best practice to use xml.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#write